# Are there SIGN operators in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, sign

Are they operators '+' and '-' to manipulate the signness of their operands?

I now know I meant unary plus and minus operators!

I've never seen this operator before.

Have they been introduced in C++11 or later C++ standards?

Comment: You mean add and subtract?

Comment: I don't mean add and subtract.

Comment: Unary + and - ? They exist since forever

Comment: Better call them unary minus and unary plus operators

Comment: You mean you can write a positive number like `+123` or a negative like `-123`? That's pretty basic and has been with C++ since the beginning. How else would one even be able to use negative numbers or values in general without an unary negation operator?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: Yes, I meant unary plus and minus!!

Comment: Easily googlable with "C++ operators" or similar terms. Second hit for me is to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), listing `+a` and `-a` in the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unary `+` and `-` have existed since the early formulations of C in the 1970s.

Note that `+` is **not** a no-op: it will widen the argument to at least an `int` type.

Finally note that `-1` is **not** a literal in C++: it is a compile-time evaluable constant expression consisting of the unary negation of the `int` literal 1.

Comment: Regarding the "not no-op", one also have to remember that in C++ these operators can also be overloaded.

Comment: It will also decay arrays, functions and capture-less lambdas into pointers :)

Comment: ^ - Which is all useful to ensure specific template argument deduction or overload resolution

Answer (score 0):

Yes, C++ has signed operators.

```
int a;
a = -20; //valid
a = a + (-30) //valid
```

Read about signed and unsigned data types [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) and unary operators [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic).